ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))
I have a telegram bot code that works great if connected from my laptop. But as soon as I uploaded it to the server, errors began in the bot.
Example: Buch - nicht definiert: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.linguee.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /english-german/search?source=auto&query=Buch (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))
Is it possible to do something about this?
I have no idea why the code doesn't work.
